# how to select the nth-child of the element with jquery?

Tags: jquery

We can use pseudo-selector the nth-child like this `$('.className:nth-child(8)')`

but what can I do if I want to use like this:

```
var cname = $('.className');
cname:nth-child(8); // this way obviously not work

Or want to use like this
var $this = $(this);
$this.nth-child(8); // I don't think so it would work
```

So, How can I implement this with jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `className` elements which are the 8th child of its parent - then use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter)

```
cname.filter(':nth-child(8)');
```

If you want `className` element at the index 8 of the given set

```
cname.eq(8);
```

Comment: does eq() supports ie7, ie8

Comment: @C-Link it is provided by jQuery so yes it is supported

Answer (score 0):

You can use [eq method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of `nth-child` but it starts with 0

So try this:

```
var cname = $('.className');
cname.eq(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  $(':nth-child(8)','.className');
```

**EDITED CODE**

```
  $(':nth-child(8)',this);
```

Comment: can I use like this: $(':nth-child(8)', $(this));

Comment: just this only not $(this)?